# Schriftliche Höflichkeitsformel – Du oder du

Tags: usage, spelling, reformed-orthography

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>
> - [Is it still good form to use a capital D for Du or Dir in a letter?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211)

In einem E-Mail an meinen Kunden schreibe ich immer *Du/Dich/Dir* (mit einem grossen *D*). Zum Beispiel:

> Bei Fragen stehen wir **Dir** gerne zur Verfügung.

Als ich mit Deutsch in meinem Job begonnen habe, habe ich immer *du/dich/dir* geschrieben und ein Kollege hat es mir korrigiert, weil es nicht höflich wäre. Ich bin überrascht, da ich immer *du* sage, wenn ich mit diesem Kunden bespreche.

Meine Fragen sind:

- Stimmt die Aussage von meinem Kollegen? Wäre es unhöflich, *du* (mit kleinem *d*) zu schreiben?
- Gibt es eigentlich drei Höflichkeitsformen auf Deutsch (*Sie* sehr höflich, *Du* mittelhöflich, *du* freundlich)? Falls ja, woher kommt das und was sind die Regeln?

Comment: Siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211 (auf Englisch).

Comment: Oh tempora, oh mores. Ich bin auch noch ein Kind der veralteten Form der Anrede ...

Comment: @teylyn: Ich denke, die Frage sollte offen bleiben, wegen der unterschiedlichen Sprachen, in denen die beiden gestellt und beantwortet sind.

Comment: @chirlu Danke ich hatte gesucht, aber keine ähnliche Frage gefunden.

Comment: Siehe auch [german.stackexchange.com/questions/7829](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7829).

Answer (score 8):

Im Prinzip wird *du* mit kleinem *d* geschrieben, wie alle anderen Personalpronomina auch (*ich*, *er*, *wir* usw.). Nur *Sie* als Höflichkeitsanrede wird großgeschrieben; nicht, weil das besonders höflich wäre, sondern um es von *sie* für die dritte Person Plural zu unterscheiden.

Das gilt zum Beispiel, wenn in einem Roman direkte Rede wiedergegeben wird:

> Er erstarrte. „Hörst du das?“
>   Er erstarrte. „Hören Sie das?“

Ein *Du* wäre an dieser Stelle falsch.

Nun gibt es (gab es, gibt es wieder) für *du* aber eine besondere Ausnahme. Nach der **alten Rechtschreibung** wurde es in Briefen und ähnlichen Texten, in denen sich das *du* konkret an den Leser wendet, großgeschrieben:

> Lieber Johann, danke, daß Du mir …

An elektronische Post hat man damals noch nicht gedacht, aber sie gehört sicher auch zu den briefartigen Texten.

Mit der **Rechtschreibreform von 1996** wurde diese Ausnahme abgeschafft. Somit galt ab dann, daß *du* auch in Briefen kleingeschrieben wird.

Mit der **Revision der Rechtschreibreform von 2006** wurde die alte Ausnahmeregel wieder eingeführt, aber nur optional – man kann demnach in Briefen wahlweise *du* oder *Du* schreiben.

All das gilt entsprechend auch für *ihr*, wenn man an mehrere Leute schreibt, und für *dich*, *dein*, *euer* usw.

---

Wenn man sich nach der neuen Rechtschreibung richtet, hat man also die freie Wahl; bleibt die Frage, ob man *du* oder *Du* wählen sollte. Sinnvollerweise nimmt man das, was beim Empfänger den besseren Eindruck hinterläßt. Leider gibt es aber zwei Gruppen von potentiellen Empfängern:

- Die eine Gruppe empfindet ein *Du* mit Großbuchstabe als Ausdruck des Respekts gegenüber dem Empfänger, entsprechend ein *du* als Zeichen mangelnden Respekts.
- Die andere Gruppe empfindet ein *du* als normal und ein *Du* als altmodisch oder gar affektiert.

Also: Wie man’s macht, ist es falsch. :-) Im Normalfall fragt man nicht, ob jemand lieber mit *du* oder mit *Du* angeschrieben werden will. Somit kann man sich entweder dem Stil des Gegenübers anpassen (schreibt es *du*, schreibe ich auch *du*, und umgekehrt) oder konsequent das benutzen, was man selbst besser findet.

Ich persönlich gehöre zur zweiten Gruppe und kann *Du* nicht leiden, deshalb schreibe ich immer *du*. Das habe ich übrigens auch schon vor 1996 getan.

Comment: Ich empfinde eigentlich das großgeschriebene "Sie" in Briefen nicht als Trick, um Verwechslungen mit der gleichlautenden Mehrzahl zu vermeiden, sondern einfach als Ausdruck des Respekts - also eine Höflichkeitsfloskel, genauso wie "Sehr geehrte", was genaugenommen auch sehr überdreht klingt (Warum ehre ich jeden, dem ich einen Brief schreibe?). Logisch weitergedacht, war es nicht ungewöhnlich, auch guten Freunden so zu zeigen, dass man sie schätzt. Enge Freunde brauchen das natürlich nicht wirlich, aber der reichen Erbtante in Amerika sollte man ein großes "Du" wohl eher doch gönnen.

Comment: @falkb: Nimm meinen fiktiven Roman. „Hören sie das?“ – „Nein, sie sind wohl weit genug weg.“ Hat also nichts mit Briefen zu tun.

Comment: ich bestreite nicht, dass es auch diese schöne Funktion hat. Aber im folgenden fiktiven Roman wird auch nicht Großschreibung zur Klärung der Doppeldeutigkeit (suchen/mögen) verwendet. "Werden Sie das Haus finden?" stellte er mir die Frage - "Ja, ich finde das gut" dachte ich mir. ;) Fand ich es gut, dass er mir die Frage stellte?