# Capitalization of pronouns in emails

Tags: pronoun, capitalization, letter

One can capitalize pronouns in mails/letters.

For example:

> Ich schreibe dir.

or

> Ich schreibe Dir.

When should it be capitalized?

Comment: Does this help? https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-it-still-good-form-to-use-a-capital-d-for-du-or-dir-in-a-letter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to be polite, you capitalize pronouns in personal speech. It's good manner and mainly used in letters.

Comment: This answer is more than incomplete, if not wrong. In short: The pronoun of address *Sie* and the corresponding possessive pronoun *Ihr* **must** be capitalized (§ 65), the other pronouns of address (*du*, *ihr*) and the corresponding possessive pronouns (*dein*, *euer*) **can** be capitalized in letters and the like (§ 66, E). All other pronouns (*er/sie/es*, *wir*, plural *sie*) and their corresponding possessive pronouns **mustn't** be capitalized (except, of course, at the beginning of a sentence).