# What is the accurate meaning of expression "Du hast einen Sparren zu viel!"

Tags: meaning, etymology, german-to-english, phrase, expression

It's from a book I'm reading and in the english translation it is translated as "You have wheels in the head!" in other translation as "You have bats in in the belfry!" However Sparren translates to rafter. Is this a common German expression? I don't need to translate it as a word just want to understand.

Sentence in context:

> Mensch, es spukt in Deinem Kopfe; Du hast einen Sparren zu viel! Du bildest Dir große Dinge ein und malst Dir eine ganze Götterwelt aus, die für Dich da sei, ein Geisterreich, zu welchem Du berufen seist, ein Ideal, das Dir winkt. Du hast eine fixe Idee!

Comment: This (without "*zu viel*") is listed in [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Sparren+haben&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou) and in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Sparren). It is a figure of speech though so it might not be in the dictionary you're using.

Comment: PS. One way to see how common an expression is is to use the DWDS usage database, [here](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=Sparren%20%26%26%20haben). It kind of depend on what you mean by "common" and what the circumstances are. In this case there are no hits on subtitles so I gather is not used much in everyday speech, but it does seem to be used by journalists. PPS. Why is "*Du*" capitalized in the quote? It seems unusual.

Comment: @RDBury The capitalised "Du" is a kind of honorific (equivalent to "Sie").  See also [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-it-still-good-form-to-use-a-capital-d-for-du-or-dir-in-a-letter).  However, at least in my impression not capitalising it is more common nowadays.  According to Duden both is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Du hast ja einen Sparren

is the colloquial (and somewhat outdated, but still my parents used to use that) expression of not being of your right mind, being crazy.

The analogy is more or less that same as with the *bats in the belfry* in English, illustrating the skull and brains (i.e., the top of a human's body) with the top floor or roof of a building.

Similar sayings relate to the same picture - with the same notion - like

> Er ist nicht ganz richtig im Oberstübchen

> Er hat einen Dachschaden

Duden mentions the figurative meaning as

> etwas, was sich anderen als kleine Verrücktheit darstellt; Spleen

and colloquial.

[Grimms Wörterbuch](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB#2) quotes Klopstock:

> der philosophische idealist
> hat, wie ihr wist,
> so was von einem narren;
> der kritische idealist
> hat, wie ihr noch vielleicht nicht wist
> auch oft wol was von mehr als einem sparren.

Interestingly, you can find references of both "einen Sparren zu viel" and "einen Sparren zu wenig" as having the same meaning.

But Grimm also has an interesting second explanation that relates *Sparren* to "Du hast ja einen Vogel" (i.e. "Spatz", "Sperling", - *Sparrow*) with the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

[Das Deutsche Sprichwörterlexikon](http://www.zeno.org/Wander-1867/A/Sparren?hl=sparren) (Dictionary of proverbs) by Karl Friedrich Wilhelm Wander dates from 1880 and shows some quotes (obviously even older). The meaning is given as

> nicht recht bei Verstand(e) sein

which google translates as

> not be in one's right mind

I admit to never have heard it.

The choice of an idiomatic translation is yours.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought that it was similar to

> Du hast Vögel (im Kopf).

Which translates to

> You have birds in your head.

I've heard people say this before which is like calling someone stupid or crazy. This sounds similar in context.

Comment: Ich kenne "Du hast einen Vogel", aber nicht die Mehrzahl "Du hast Vögel". Das scheint vielleicht eine spitzfindige Unterscheidung zu sein, aber wieso hört oder liest man nirgends die Mehrzahlform? Inwiefern ist es ähnlich zu "e. Sparren zuviel haben"?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @tofro's answer: the original meaning of "Sparren" is that of a timber holding the roof construction. I am no engineer but as to my knowledge this piece of wood is called "rafter" or "principal".

The proverbial meaning of being crazy comes from the notion of ones "roof" (the head, respectively the mind) being misbuilt. "Dach" (roof) alluding to the head or mind is common in german proverbs: "einen *Dachschaden* haben" ("roof damage") also means being crazy, and for "einen Vogel haben" ("to have a bird" - which commonly builds nests on the roof) goes the same. Also "eine aufs Dach kriegen" ("to get one on the roof") means getting hit on the head - either physically or by being dressed down.

Comment: The head is not that frequently compared to a roof, except for the Schädeldecke, cp. obsolete *Schädeldach* (skullcap, crown, calvaria), which might be more generally explained from vessels, or folk etymology. The surface analysis of the phrases that you have mentioned do not stand to reason as far as their origin remains obscure. Somebody whose actual house has permanent roof damage in winter is guaranteed to suffer one illness or another. It's English where the idea is common, although *temple* (respectively *dome*) immediately relates to *temporalis* in Latin, further origin obscure.

Comment: Or simply put, to show that "rafter" is the *original meaning*, you have to show where the word came from. It sounds like your answer would be *from the dictionary*. The dictionaries named in this thread are however known to be full of gaps and mistakes, just like a Sparren has *notches* to set it in place, cp. *Aussparung*. At least the Sparren is belast-bar, it bears weight. Is wirklich nicht aus-zuhalten hier, einfach un-aus-träglich mit diesen Einträgen. Habt doch erbarmen.

Comment: @vectory: Looking up "Sparren" in a german dictionary as well as the german wikipedia reveals that it is a part of a roof construction. How much more proof for the original meaning of "Sparren" do you need? Second, looking up "Sparren" in dict.leo.org translates it as "principal" or "rafter", which is what i said and what correlates to the german dictionaries. Furthermore, if you can't stand what i write i suggest you don't read it.

Comment: @vectory: one more thing: that "temple/Tempel/templum" "immediately relates" to "tempus" is *ONE* out of several *hypotheses* and in no way an assured fact. You grossly misrepresent the state of affairs here.

Answer (score -2):

Die bisherigen Antworten überzeugen kaum. Für Pejorative gilt im Allgemeinen, dass eine ältere Herkunft angenommen werden darf als schriftlich nachweisbar ist und zwar zwingend, wenn bisherige Deutungsversuche anderweitig in die Leere gehen. Dafür ist erstens eine relativ genaue Entsprechung im literarischen Vergleich erforderlich, wenn auf Typologie abgestellt wird. Für historische Vergleiche gilt das um so mehr.

Zweitens sollte die Etymologie der jeweiligen Worte den Vergleich unbedingt zulassen, was gerade in dem ersten Punkt entbehrlich sein mag, wenn man schon gewillt ist paralellen zu ziehen und zum Beispiel Lehnübersetzungen anzunehmen.

Der Kopf ist ein beliebtes Ziel vieler Metaphern, doch die Behauptung allein genügt nicht zum Beweis, weil ebenso andere Metaphern herhalten mögen, bspw. Tiervergleiche (Kathryn Allan, *Metaphor and metonymy, a diachronic approach*, widmet diesen ein Kapitel), vgl. *Sperling, sparrow*, sowie *springen* (en.wiktionary: Proto-Indo-European **sperH-*). Entsprechende Metaphern sind nachvollziehbar:

- *einen Sprung in der Schüssel haben*, d.h. *hirnrissig*, sowie bereits angemerkt
- *einen Vogel haben* (Grimm, s. oben @Takkat)
- a kangaroo loose in the top paddock
- a few spanners short of a tool box

Der Vergleich ist plausibel, da "einen Vogel haben" oft mit einer den Kopf andeutenden Gebärde verbunden wird. Der Vergleich hinkt dennoch. Selbst wenn die "Schüssel" als Schädelknochen zu interpretieren ist, ist ein "Vogel" doch kaum als *Riss* irgendeiner Art zu verstehen; *Sprung* in dieser Bedeutung "seit etwa 1700" [Pfeifer]. Mit weiteren Ableitungen wie "bei dir piept's" stellt der Vogel eine eigene Metapher dar.

##### der Jargon uff'n Bau

Dabei ist prinzipiel zu unterscheiden, ob hier wirklich der *Dachsparren* gemeint sein kann: Angesichts der Metapher *Dachschaden* erscheint das gut möglich, doch wie viel *zu viel* ein Schaden sein sollte, wäre demnach noch nicht offensichtlich, weil zumeist irgendein Mangel bezeichnet wird ("Du hast se doch nicht mehr alle") ist der Wechsel gegenüber "zu viel" so oder so zu erklären. Die weitere Herkunft von *Sparren* ist soweit leider nicht offensichtlich, wie Pfeifer zugibt: "Herkunft unbekannt" ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Sparren), vgl. *Speer*).

Als tragendes Element wäre in der Dachkonstruktion zwar mit *Barren* eventuel an *bher- "tragen; gebären" zu denken, obwohl das initiale *S-* dann noch einer Begründung bedarf. Es erscheint hinsichtlich des Dachsparren jedoch abwegig etwa einen Fugenlaut anzunehmen.

Wichtig ist erstmal nur, dass Fachausdrücke konservativ sind und sich gerade deshalb weitgehend unberührt von der Umgangssprache entwickeln können. Dies bleibt noch zu klären. Ohnedies kann nur eine geschickte Auslegung des Idioms die Etymologie selbst erklären.

##### Konnotation

Aus semantischer Sicht legt die Zitatstelle zumindest einen psychologischen Bezugspunkt nahe,

> «Mensch, es spukt in Deinem Kopfe; Du hast einen Sparren zu viel!»

Behavioral betrachtet ist das ergebnisoffen, weil jedwede Verhaltensart darunter gefasst werden kann, ohne die Bedeutung des Bezugswortes wirklich zu verstehen, was ggf. in schwieriger Übersetzung niederschlägt. *Bat* ("You have bats in the belfry") hilft kaum weiter, siehe aber *bat* "Fledermaus", *batton* "Schlagstock", ebenso *beater* "wing", niederländisch *fleder* "wing". Für den Sitz des Verstandes u.ä. Abstraktionen werden verschiedene Konzepte betreffender Köperteile in Betracht kommen.

Etwas pathetisch dünkt mich, der Spruch könnte viel negativer gewesen sein als eine Unterhaltsame Geschichte herhält. * *Du hast einen Sparren zu [fühlen]*, vgl. *Wer nicht hören will muss fühlen*. So wie *Prügel* die *Prügelstrafe* als auch den *Prügelstock* benennt, wäre dies ein Metonym, so wie die Balkenform des Baustoffs bezeichnend und *Dachbalken* synonym ist. Das ist dennoch sehr indirekt, vgl. *Sparringspartner*, *spar* "beam". Ohnehin ist *fühlen* in der Etymologie unsicher, während *viel* gut vertreten ist, vgl. *fully, poly-, pleo-*, usw.

#### Das Geometrische Mittel

Der Ansatz bietet da noch mehr. *Speiche, Speicher*, *speichern*, verhält sich 1:1 zu *Sparren, sperren, sparen*, bzw. *verbergen* usw. *block*, *bank* usf. – das Schlüssel-Schloss-Prinzip.

Ebenso erscheint *span* in (siehe Adelung [5.1](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=Adelung&sigle=Adelung&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=DP00154#1), insbesonder auch *Spanne* als Schiffsdurchmesser) möglicher Weise relevant, cp. *spanking*, das führt hier aber zu weit. Laut Adelung ist *Spanische Wand* spanisch, was Wikipedia wiederum in Abrede stellt. M.M.n. ist *span* für die Art Lattenrost Bezugsword, sowie *Wand* regulär als aus *Weide* geflochten gilt, vgl. "through the grape wine". Hinsichtlich ‹#› (engl. "fence") vgl. *nicht mehr alle Latten am Zaun haben*. Für Partner gilt *Spannmann* (?), vgl. *Passmann*.

Andernfalls verhärtet sich mit *Späne* zumindest der Verdacht auf *sper-, vgl. *Spreu*.

Einerseits erinnert dies an "spick and span new", Herkunft umstritten, ebenso "funkelnagelneu" u.ä. da Funken wortwörtlich *sprühen*, vgl. *spark*, *spunk*.

##### Stilmittel

Genau daran könnte die geistige Metapher *Spuk* anschließen, s. a. *Gespenst, G'spenstli*, *Hirn-Gespinnst*, jedenfalls *keinen Funken verstand haben*, vgl. *sprite*, *spirit*, *esprit*, davon ab *vor Ideen sprühen*, *to spark an idea*, oder *to spurn on*. Von mehr will ich gar nicht spechen.

Andererseits ist mangels mir ersichtlicher Ausschlusskriterien – das wär OP's Job – ein sporadischer Wechsel wie *zerren* gegen *to tug*, *ziehen* (/tsi:n/) beachtlich, bzw. Berliner *Wagen* mit /ɣ / (stimmhafter uvularer Frikativ, Zäpfchen-r):

- Vgl. *spackig*, bzw. *Spargeltarzan*, *spärlich* wie im Volkslied, "Sparrenlanger Hansel / nudeldicke Dirn", reim auf "Birn", wohl ein Lehnwort. Wikipedia weis mehr.

> **[Spannenlanger Hansel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spannenlanger_Hansel)**
>
> - “Oft wird eine Herkunft im salzburgischen bzw. alpenländischen Raum vermutet.[8][11] Wenn dies stimmen sollte, ist möglicherweise die Textvariante „Daumenlanger Hansl“ die ursprüngliche Form, die in Österreich auch bis heute noch verbreitet ist."

Weiter unten im Text ist es wegen der großen Variation jedoch unsicher. Der salzburgische Sprachraum kann zu Völkerwanderungszeiten noch ganz woanders gewesen sein, der alpenländische Raum noch anders besetzt.

#### Vorsprung durch Technik

Ein entscheidendes Merkmal des Dachsparren ist sicherlich die Bearbeitung. Damit der Sparren auf dem Kantholz sicher aufliegen kann, wird das Holz eingeschnitten. Ob dies bedeutsam für die Bezeichnung *Sparren* ist, sei dahingestellt. Jedenfalls dürfte von einer *Aussparung* zu reden sein, so wie *Marke* sich zu *merken* verhält (s. o. zu *sparen*), vgl. *Spur*. Entsprechend finden sich *Spätzle* (wohl zu *Spitze*) wie *Schmarren* ("Herkunft ungewiß" [[Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schmarren)]).

Ob das Ende des Dachs zur Traufe hin, das über der tragenden Wand hervorragt, wohl deshalb "Vorsprung" heißt, weil dieser Teil *vor* dem besagten *Einschnitt* liegt, sowie der Ober-Arm über dem Ellenbogen liegt (vgl. ἁρμός "shoulder-joint", अरत्नि "elbow, ulna")? Während dafür hoffentlich Belege nachweisbar sind (s. DBW: springen 1.c, "vielleicht gehört hierher auch sprung als bezeichnung der vordersten oder kürzesten seite eines stagsegels", spur 11. "spur im deichbau, loch für den untersten soden der besodung." "spur im schiffbau, hölzernes oder eisernes zapfenloch, viereckig oder rund, ..."), kann darüber hinaus über einen engeren Zusammenhang zum Erwerb der Schriftsprache als Verwaltungsinstrument nur spekuliert werden.

Schließlich soll [Barren](https://dwds.de/wb/Barren) [nach Pfeifer] aus Latein entlehnt sein. Soweit dieser Ansatz oben schon gerechtfertigt war, sind weitere Vergleiche nicht ausgeschlossen, da dessen vulgärlateinische Herkunft weiter unklar ist (en.wt: VL [*barra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/barra)).

##### Italiänisch im Vergleich

- *sbarra* < Latein *barra + s-* bestätigt die genannte Vermutung, doch ist nicht sofort ersichtlich, woher die Nebenbedeutung stammt: "stroke (of a pen etc)". Da Adelung betont, Späne werden durch Spaltung hergestellt, ist die naheliegende Vermutung nicht sofort anzunehmen, dass Streichung erst auf *sbarrare* "to cancel" folge.

Übrigens kennen schlagende Burschenschaften ebenso den *Schmiss*, eine durch die Waffe beigebrachte Verletzung, sowie vermutlich auch den **Rauschmiss** - natürlich haben alle zuviel Trickfilm geschaut, und glauben dass ein Rausschmiss im hohen Bogen zu erfolgen hat, dass der betroffene geradezu auf die Fresse fliegt. Bei *zu vielen* oder einer stark blutenden Verletzung werden sportliche Duelle jedenfalls beendet. S. Bzgl. *Raussschmiss* ferner urgermanisch [*hrau](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hrawaz).

- Italiänisch *sprangare* steht synonym zu *sbarra*, dies wohl aus der dem Althochdeutschen verwandten lombardischen Sprache. Es gehört zu Dt. *Spange*, das -r- aus Supperposition von *sbarra*, lt. [it.wt](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/spranga). Vgl. *sprangare* "to hit or strike with a bar or bolt".

Das vermag ebensowenig die Spreu vom Weizen zu trennen, denn engl. *star spangled* steht der Späne in nichts nach und wiedermals heißt es, "etymology uncertain" bei [en.wt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spangle#English). Die Verortung der Lombardei südlich der Alpen sagt eben auch nichts über engl. *sparring* aus, das seinerseits wegen der Sportart *ringen* doch fraglich bleiben muss.

- *spada* "Schwert", Lat. *spatha*, ist vorallem als de. *Spaten*, *Spatel*, bekannt, entlehnt aus altgriechisch σπάθη, "any broad blade, of wood or metal".

Dazu zählt auch *Spachtel*, s. oben zu *spackig*,

- *spaccato* "broken", wohl zu lombard. *spahhan "to cleave, to split" ([en.WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaccare#Italian), [it.wt](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaccare)).

Vgl. *Spagat*, *die Schere machen*, *aus dem Leim gehen*.

- *balaustro* "pillar", der Form nach vom Namen einer Pflanze, über Griechisch aus einer semitischen Sprache, vgl. Aramäisch *balatz* "wild pomegranate flower", vgl. *banister*, s.d.: "Alteration of earlier *barrester, ballester*, corruptions of baluster" ([en.WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baluster#English)), vgl. *Balustrade*

Ich will mich nicht zu weit aus dem Banister lehnen, doch scheint mir *ballast* ebenso plausibel, da die klassisch bauchige Form markant und architektonisch begründet ist, vgl. *Birne*. Die florale Verzierung ist dagegen zweitrangig und der mittelalterliche Versuch, alle Sprachen auf die vermeintliche Sprache Gottes zurückzuführen, kaum der Rede wert. Das geht ins Leere, denn "The origin of the first part is uncertain" ([en.WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ballast#German)). Deshalb gilt, *Schuster, bleib bei deinem Leisten*.

Ob *Last*, bzw. *Latte* zu *Leiste* zählt, sei vorerst dahingestellt. In Altlitauisch *klóti* "hinbreiten, spreiten", wozu wohl zählen *suklótinas* "zusammengelegt, passend", *klojìmas, klójimas* "Tenne, Dreschdiele", *apklotis* "Deckbett", *paklotis* "Lager, Streu", etc. ([ALEW](https://alew.hu-berlin.de/dict/1199)) liegt ein treffender Vergleich mit *Leiste* vor, zumal *Streu* noch deutlicher hervortritt, s. *Tenne*. Man muss sich wohl eine Blöckhütte vorstellen mit Halbetage zum schlafen. *Stairs*, *upstairs* ist deswegen für *balaustro* nicht zu vergessen. Indoeuropäische scheinen unsicher. Vgl. *Geländer, Leiter, Leitzins, Leihzins, Deckeln*. Näher ans Dach wird dieser Ausflug nicht mehr kommen. Vgl. *ceiling*, *die Stimmung ist im Keller.

Dagegen ist der vermeintliche Praefix auch in *Brüstung* beachtlich. Einerseits ragt diese auf Brust-Höhe, doch ist nicht auszuschließen, dass das Wort überhaupt vom Brustschutz kommt, vgl. *bra, brassier* "BH" (zu *brachial*, logisch der Untermarmhalter, muss ich anerkennen wie vorhergesagt), bzw. *brass* "Kupfer", oder *brazier*, altfranzösisch *brese* "embers" (s.o. *Funken*). Andererseits ist *Rüstung* zu erahnen.

Das führt weiter zu nichts, weil für den Spruch selbst kein genauer einzugrenzender Ursprung zu erwarten ist, der bspw. Französisch *Brand* "Schwert" wie PIE *ph2- auszuschließen vermag. Es ist zum verzweifeln.

S. a. *schizzo* zu *sch(e/i)da* "Splitter, Gedicht".

> Trotzdem zeigt er bisher keinerlei psychopathologischen Züge oder aggressive „Sparren“. [[Die Zeit, 01.07.1966, Nr. 27] bei DWDS]

Ob das schnippische *Spitzen* sein sollen oder was anderes, lässt sich kaum sagen. Am ehesten Ende gehört es noch mit *fesseria* "nonsense" zu *gʷʰen-"murder", bzw.  *dʰgʷʰey- "to die", eigentlich urgermanisch *banjō "wound" ([en.wt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/banj%C5%8D)).